# CSS doesn't render correctly on iOS when zooming in

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I want to render a sidebar. My CSS works pretty well when rendered on a desktop browser, even when I zoom in. However, on an iOS device, zooming in on the page (via pinch-to-zoom) renders the sidebar over the content. Last I checked, I remember getting the same behavior on the default Android browser and Chrome Beta.

I put up a (mostly) minimal demo page that illustrates this behavior: http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~dange/test/test.html

If you visit with a mobile browser such as mobile Safari, though, we get this:
[iOS screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pM0x.jpg)

Here is the CSS used to render that page:

```
/* Sidebar */

header {
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: auto;
  top: 0;
}

#site-title {
  font: bold 36px sans-serif;
  margin: 1em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Navigation menu in sidebar */

nav {
  font: 18px sans-serif;
  margin: 2em auto;
  width: 140px;
}

    nav > ul {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0 10px;
    }

    nav li {
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
    }

    nav a {
      display: block;
      padding: 8px 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

/* Content "Pane" */

#content,
footer {
  margin-left: 220px;
  max-width: 620px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

#content p {
  font: 18px / 30px serif;
}

footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #AAA;
  font: 14px serif;
}
```

...and a simplified HTML document:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <h1 id="site-title">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </header>

  <section id="content">
    <article>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>...</p>
      <p>...</p>
    </article>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <p>...</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

I am aware that this isn't an optimal layout for mobile browsers (and I do plan to improve my actual site so that it will look nice on a mobile device). But in the meantime, I do want to get rid of this issue.

Comment: It might be worth using em instead of px.

Comment: Why should I? (serious question)

Comment: Pixels should mean actual pixels which don't make much sense when you have ultra hd displays. This won't solve your problem but it is best practice when dealing with a wide variety of screen resolutions. Read http://m.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the position fixed for header, I can't really test it, tried it on fiddle but the zooming does not seem to work the same as I expected. but if your header tag is fixed on the left then it would make sense for it to be on the left. It seems iOS treats zoom as a resize of the window or something so it forces the css the react or something like that

Comment: In my case the fixed position for the header is desired :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed a similar problem on my sites by using a wrapper right inside the body tag.

```
#wrapper{
     width:840px;
     overflow:auto;
}
```

BUT I think a sidebar on mobile isn't a good idea unless it can be dynamically hidden. When on mobile it might be better to stack the sidebar on top of the content:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
     #content, nav{width:100%; margin:10px 0; position:relative;}
}
```

The above is untested.

Comment: Your mentioning of "overflow" gave me inspiration and reminded me that i already used the z-index for the two divs. The trick is to give the navigation not only a less z-index than the main content but give it a negative z-index. For that inspiration you get the +50. Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to give the navigation element ("header") not only a less z-index than the main content but give it a negative z-index like -3. Give the main content div a z-index of +4 or whatever.

When you now zoom in with Mobile Safari on the main content, the navigation element will still be there as before but hidden behind the main content until you zoom out again.

Have fun!

Edit: Negative is not such a good idea since it makes the links untouchable. At least in my case ;-)

Edit 2: The z-index seems to work on Mobile Safari only on elements whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative.